# Updating the state on every post request

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

hey guys i have a form in my react redux project so upon submitting form i call an Action that hits post api to insert document to mongodb , so also i want is to update the state everytime so that as soon as i submit form my state gets updated and then i render them below (as array of objects)

Form.js

```
class Form extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      taskName: "",
      taskDescription: "",

    };
  }



  handleSubmit = () => {
    this.props.addTask(this.state);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="m-4">
        <div className="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
          {" "}
          <h2 className=" ">Pomodoro Tasks</h2>
          <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={()=>window.location.reload()}>Refresh</button>
        </div>
        <form>
        <div className="form-group ">
          <label>Task Name</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            className="form-control"
            onChange={(e) => this.setState({ taskName: e.target.value })}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label>Task Description</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            className="form-control"
            onChange={(e) => this.setState({ taskDescription: e.target.value })}
          />
        </div>


        </form>

        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={(e) => this.handleSubmit(e)}>
          Submit
        </button>

       ////render here the state
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {

  return state
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { addTask })(Form);
```

Actions.js

```
export const addTask = (details) => {
  return async (dispatch ,getState) =>{

    axios.post('/add_task', details)
      .then(function (response) {
        Swal.fire('Tasks Added !')
        dispatch({type:POSTDATA,payload:response.data})
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        Swal.fire('Error in adding to database')
        console.log(error);
      });

  };
};

export const getTask = () => {
  return async (dispatch ,getState) =>{
    axios.get('/get_task')
      .then(function (response) {
        dispatch({type:GETDATA,payload:response.data})
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
};
```

reducer.js

```
const postPomodoro = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case POSTDATA:
      return action.payload; //well this is only returning one object that is inserted at that time i need to 
somehow get all the previous data too that are inserted in order to update state with all data and then render it.

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
const getPomodoro = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {

    case GETDATA:
      return {...state,tasks:action.payload};
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

i tried it in reducer like

```
 case POSTDATA:
      return {...state,task:action.payload};
```

but this also gives me back the recent data that gets inserted not all the data that were inserted previously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to merge the data in state instead of overriding it. Use a spread syntax in your reducer to achieve this like below

```
const postPomodoro = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case POSTDATA:
      return [...state, action.payload]; 

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Once you update the state in the reducer, you can access it in the component by using connect and mapStateToProps

```
const Comp = (props) => {
   // iterate over props.postTask and render
}
const mapStateProps = (state) => {
   return {
      postTask: state.postPomodoro
   }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Comp)
```

Comment: can u tell me why {...state,tasks:action.payload}; doesnt work ?

Comment: That is because, state is defined an array and need to remain and array post update

Comment: just one last doubt on refreshing my page i called my action and a new reducer called getPomodoro and update state like   case GETDATA: return {...state,tasks:action.payload};  and now i want to render it but until i refresh my app i am updating state in postPomodoro  as u answered  and want to show the state of postPomodoro........ how do i do that ? how do i decide when to show which reduers state ?any guideline ?

Comment: now if i refresh i want to render the data that i get via my getPomodoro reducer otherwise  from my postPomodoro to render it

Comment: get both the data from reducer, if getPomodoro data is available render it, else render the post data

Comment: hope u might understand what i am trying to say now......so i was adding post and meanwhile rendering all the post below it from post reducer....i refershed and this time i rendered post from getPomodoro..but then again if i add post i rendered the one post that i added just now.....so the previous post that were to be with postPomodoro gets lost on refreshing ..how could i tackle that ?